# JSP - Value from tag attribute

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I've got a problem with getting the value in `<jsp:body>` of `ttt` attribute. The following code does not work. I have spend too long on this, so I'm asking here. Can someone show me the proper way?

code fragment:

```
<jsp:element name="h3">
    <jsp:attribute name="ttt">
        ${param.txt}
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>
        ${ttt} <-- this displays nothing
    </jsp:body>
</jsp:element>
```

Comment: What is the value of `param.txt`

Comment: String type - sth like "abc", its working i checked the code that is genrated is : `<h3 ttt="abc"></h3>`

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the variable in jsp by using `<c:set>` tag. A quick tutorial for your reference, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm.

Comment: I know I can use <c:set> but i wanted to obtain the value from the tag attribute. Can't it be done ?